# sql count messing up when joining table to itself

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49008/1/0). I have a table with questions where each question falls into a category and I have to find user averages of each category. I think it is working fine but I wanted to add a total that shows the total number of answers being included in the average for each user. I can not figure out what to put in my where clause to actually return the total number of questions for each user. Whether I include userid,QID,or choice it is giving me astronomical numbers.

Query SQL:

```
DECLARE @tblTmpCatStats TABLE (userid NVARCHAR(10),cat1_mean FLOAT,cat2_mean FLOAT,cat3_mean FLOAT,cat4_mean FLOAT,N FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @tblTmpCatStats SELECT d.userid
    ,AVG(CAST(c1.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,AVG(CAST(c2.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,AVG(CAST(c3.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,AVG(CAST(c4.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,COUNT(d.userid)
FROM tblTmpDemographics d
JOIN tblTmpDemographics c1 ON d.userid = c1.userid
JOIN tblTmpDemographics c2 ON d.userid = c2.userid
JOIN tblTmpDemographics c3 ON d.userid = c3.userid
JOIN tblTmpDemographics c4 ON d.userid = c4.userid
WHERE c1.QID IN ('1','5')
AND c2.QID IN ('2','6')
AND c3.QID IN ('3','7')
AND c4.QID IN ('4','8')
GROUP BY d.userid
SELECT * FROM @tblTmpCatStats
```

I am trying to make N eqaul to the total number choices included in the AVG

Setup SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTmpDemographics (userid NVARCHAR(10),QID INT,choice NVARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO tblTmpDemographics (userid,QID,choice)
SELECT 'user1',1,'5' UNION ALL SELECT 'user1',2,'3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1',3,'4' UNION ALL SELECT 'user1',4,'5' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1',5,'5' UNION ALL SELECT 'user1',6,'3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user1',7,'4' UNION ALL SELECT 'user1',8,'5' UNION ALL

SELECT 'user2',1,'3' UNION ALL SELECT 'user2',2,'2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2',3,'3' UNION ALL SELECT 'user2',4,'5' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2',5,'3' UNION ALL SELECT 'user2',6,'2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2',7,'3' UNION ALL SELECT 'user2',8,'5' UNION ALL

SELECT 'user3',1,'2' UNION ALL SELECT 'user3',2,'1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3',3,'5' UNION ALL SELECT 'user3',4,'5' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3',5,'2' UNION ALL SELECT 'user3',6,'1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3',7,'5' UNION ALL SELECT 'user3',8,'5' UNION ALL

SELECT 'user4',1,'4' UNION ALL SELECT 'user4',2,'3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user4',3,'3' UNION ALL SELECT 'user4',4,'5' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user4',5,'4' UNION ALL SELECT 'user4',6,'3' UNION ALL
SELECT 'user4',7,'3' UNION ALL SELECT 'user4',8,'5' GO
```

Why is it returning 128 and not 8?

Comment: Please provide a complete question. The link to the fiddle is nice but the question is useless without that fiddle...

Comment: @lazfish what is the result that you want or are expecting?

Comment: I am hoping for N to equal the total number of choices per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.userid
    ,AVG(CAST(c1.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,AVG(CAST(c2.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,AVG(CAST(c3.choice AS FLOAT))
    ,AVG(CAST(c4.choice AS FLOAT))
    , d.cnt
FROM
(
  SELECT userid, count(*) cnt
  from tblTmpDemographics
  group by userid
) d
INNER JOIN tblTmpDemographics c1 
  ON d.userid = c1.userid
INNER JOIN tblTmpDemographics c2 
  ON d.userid = c2.userid
INNER JOIN tblTmpDemographics c3 
  ON d.userid = c3.userid
INNER JOIN tblTmpDemographics c4 
  ON d.userid = c4.userid
WHERE c1.QID IN ('1','5')
  AND c2.QID IN ('2','6')
  AND c3.QID IN ('3','7')
  AND c4.QID IN ('4','8')
GROUP BY d.userid,  d.cnt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49008/30)

Answer (score 2):

The method you've chosen to get your results fails to bring you the correct count simply because all your joins, even though they are further filtered, potentially can (and some of them eventually do) result in multiple matches per row and that, in turn, produces mini-[Cartesian products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in the intermediate resulting set, the one that is ultimately being aggregated.

The suggestion by @bluefeet works because the count is calculated separately, but it still doesn't fix the Cartesian product effects in general. Your averages turn out correct merely because they are *averages*, as opposed to *counts* or *sums*. Essentially, they are, of course, sums divided by counts, and since both operands are factored identically, your averages end up correct regardless of the effects of the Cartesian products. However, if you try SUM or COUNT on your `choice` values, you'll see incorrect results again.

You could instead use conditional aggregating, like this:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  cat1_mean = AVG(CASE WHEN QID IN (1, 5) THEN CAST(choice AS float) END),
  cat2_mean = AVG(CASE WHEN QID IN (2, 6) THEN CAST(choice AS float) END),
  cat3_mean = AVG(CASE WHEN QID IN (3, 7) THEN CAST(choice AS float) END),
  cat4_mean = AVG(CASE WHEN QID IN (4, 8) THEN CAST(choice AS float) END),
  N = COUNT(*)
FROM tblTmpDemographics
GROUP BY userid
;
```

Or you could use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) feature of SQL Server, like this:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  cat1_mean,
  cat2_mean,
  cat3_mean,
  cat4_mean,
  N
FROM (
  SELECT
    userid,
    choice = CAST(choice AS float),
    QuestionGroup = CASE
      WHEN QID IN (1, 5) THEN 'cat1_mean'
      WHEN QID IN (2, 6) THEN 'cat2_mean'
      WHEN QID IN (3, 7) THEN 'cat3_mean'
      WHEN QID IN (4, 8) THEN 'cat4_mean'
    END,
    N = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY userid)
  FROM tblTmpDemographics
) s
PIVOT (
  AVG(choice) FOR QuestionGroup IN (
    cat1_mean,
    cat2_mean,
    cat3_mean,
    cat4_mean
  )
) p
;
```

or like this (same as before, but with a common table expression):

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    userid,
    choice = CAST(choice AS float),
    QuestionGroup = CASE
      WHEN QID IN (1, 5) THEN 'cat1_mean'
      WHEN QID IN (2, 6) THEN 'cat2_mean'
      WHEN QID IN (3, 7) THEN 'cat3_mean'
      WHEN QID IN (4, 8) THEN 'cat4_mean'
    END,
    N = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY userid)
  FROM tblTmpDemographics
)
SELECT
  userid,
  cat1_mean,
  cat2_mean,
  cat3_mean,
  cat4_mean,
  N
FROM marked
PIVOT (
  AVG(choice) FOR QuestionGroup IN (
    cat1_mean,
    cat2_mean,
    cat3_mean,
    cat4_mean
  )
) p
;
```

Both methods can be tested and played with at SQL Fiddle:

- [conditional aggregation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49008/38)
- [PIVOT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49008/40) ([with a CTE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49008/42))

Answer (score 1):

Its a slighly crude way of acheiving it, but changing the

`COUNT(d.userID)`

to

`COUNT(distinct d.qid)`

gives a count of 8 for each user.

Comment: This works in the fiddle but my real query has 10 questions per category and the query runs and runs (been going for like 4 mins as of this comment) so something is wrong with this.

Comment: This finally did work (correctly) but took 6 minutes or so. Is there a quicker way? I am running a lot of things at once with this query and this is by FAR the longest to run.

Comment: Is it still slow if you remove the `N` column all together?

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid, count(userid) cnt from tblTmpDemographics group by userid
```

this shows 8 - you must have run the inserts twice.

Comment: There are 8.  Note that there are two rows inserted per line.